# JavaScript performance benchmark in handling events at parent for all child elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Handling events for several child elements in bubbling phase at parent node is common. However, I am not sure if there are any performance issues in it.
For instance, consider the following structure:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>child1</div>
    <div>child2</div>
    <div>child3</div>
</div>
```

Now if I want to handle `onclick` on each of the children, I can attach the handler to each child div or just a single handler to the parent div as the event is going to bubble up.

So I was curious what is the best practice? Are there any performance concerns in the two approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a big number of childs I would recommend you to go for [Event Delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/).

By experience I can tell you that adding event handlers to a *very large* number of elements may give you performance issues, memory leaks and browser locks (primarily in IE).

Event delegation in those instances is a very simple, light and good alternative.